# Solution of this { Fault String End Element in Web Service}

Tags: android, android-websettings

I have PDF Files list through web service link in my android application,when i was open my PDF its working perfect after i came back my list,Now i click(second time)same PDF file its not opem(working) the following error accord..help me pls..

**ERROR:**

```
I/faultstringendElement(664): FaultStringSystem.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\web\users\KnotBiz\c.knotbiz.com\000970\CON000970000016-1474.pdf' because it is being used by another process.
I/faultstringendElement(664):at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
I/faultstringendElement(664):at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
I/faultstringendElement(664):at KnotBiz.Mobile.WebService.MobileService.PrintContract(Int64 UserId, Int64 eventId, Nullable`1 id)
I/faultstringendElement(664):--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: write a condition to check whether the file is being used or not. If it is being used try to close it in the code and then write your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are already accessing that file -  because it is being used by another process. Depending on your implantation, you need to release the file when you close it or check if it is already open.